# ERROR 1064 (42000) SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I am having trouble importing a schema in mysql.

```
mysql -u user -p print < jasmine.sql
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 23: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '(14) NOT NULL,
>    `job_id` tinytext NOT
>   NULL, 
>    `printer` tinytext NOT NULL, 
>    `u' at line 3

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE `jobs_log` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
  `date` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
  `job_id` tinytext NOT NULL, 
  `printer` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `user` tinytext NOT NULL, 
  `server` tinytext NOT NULL, 
  `title` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `copies` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0', 
  `pages` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0', 
  `options` tinytext NOT NULL, 
  `doc` tinytext NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`) 
) TYPE=MyISAM COMMENT='Lists all the jobs successfully sent for printing';
```

I am using Mysql-Server Version 5.5.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `timestamp` instead of `timestamp(14)`. As far as i know, there is a timestamp(N) deprecation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is pretty clear.  `Timestamp` does not take a length parameter.  Use:

```
date timestamp NOT NULL,
```

However, if this is just a date, then use `date`:

```
`date` date NOT NULL;
```

EDIT:

And then change `TYPE` to `ENGINE` (thanks to Arun).

Comment: Also should change TYPE to ENGINE !

Comment: Trank you! New Error                                                                           mysql -u user -p print < jasmine.sql
Enter password: 
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 23: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''TYPE=MyISAM COMMENT=Lists all the jobs successfully sent for printing'' at line 14

Answer (score 0):

timestamp doesnt have length property!

When upgrading to MySQL 5.5 or later, you must convert TYPE to use ENGINE instead.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE jobs_log (
id mediumint(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,
date timestamp,
job_id tinytext NOT NULL,
printer tinytext NOT NULL,
user tinytext NOT NULL,
server tinytext NOT NULL,
title tinytext NOT NULL,
copies smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
pages smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
options tinytext NOT NULL,
doc tinytext NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)ENGINE = MyIsam COMMENT='Lists all the jobs successfully sent for printing';
```

Answer (score -1):

Timestamp doesnt have length property, so replace the `timestamp(14)` with `timestamp()`.
MyISAM is an engine, so replace the `TYPE` with `ENGINE`.